# Save huge strings

Tags: c++, string

I am writing the code which should use several huge strings.These strings are known before the code starts to run.Strings are of the form:
text1
text2
text3
...
textn

Each text is some sentence (which can have a spaces.
I prefer not to save it in file and read from file afterwords.
How do I save it in strings?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: If they are huge, why don't you want to put them in a file? They will just make your executable as huge

Comment: What is huge for you 1MB, 1GB or even 1PB?

Comment: Use a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure))

Comment: Sorry but lol that is not huge.

Comment: @Yakov: OK, that doesn't sound huge. What platform are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings are constant, I suggest placing the text into a separate file.  This is a common solution to resolve locals and language translate issues.

**text.cpp:**

```
const char Text1[] = "text1";
const char Text2[] = "text2";
//...
```

**text.hpp:**

```
#ifndef TEXT_HPP  
#define TEXT_HPP  
extern const char Text1[];
extern const char Text2[];
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string str = "huge string...";
  filebuf fb;
  fb.open("test.txt", ios::out);
  ostream os(&fb);
  os << str;
  fb.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think he stated he doesn't want to save them into a file. So basically the first line of your `main()` function does the job... He just wants a place where to store them (e.g. like Windows resources).